# android softkeyboard event

Tags: android-widget

Could someone please let me know which events to fire to display and hide the softkeyboard including the event listeners?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for,

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myEdit);
InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
mgr.showSoftInput(editText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

And to close it again:

```
InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
mgr.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Remember, the soft keyboard will only display on devices that do not have a physical keyboard.

Comment: thanks James, however, I am trying to fire off this event from the TextView. Is it possible?